# Meteor, publish:composite. how to access joined data in the template?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-publications

So I used publishComposite to do a collection join in Meteor. I have a parent collection (Subscriptions) with a user_id foreign key. I look up the user name in the Meteor.users collection to get the actual username, but how do I actually print this in the html template. My subscription data is there but how do I actually refer to the username?

Here is the publish code:

```
//publish subscriptions course view
Meteor.publishComposite('adminCourseSubscriptions', function(courseId){
  return {
    //get the subs for the selected course
    find: function(){
        return Subscriptions.find(
            {course_id: courseId}
        );
    },

    children: 
    [
        {   
            //get the subscriber details for the course
            find: function(sub){
                return Meteor.users.find({_id:sub.user_id});
            }

        }

    ]
  };

});
```

here are the template subdcriptions:

```
Template.adminCourseDetail.helpers({
  courseDetail: function(id){
    var id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
    return Courses.findOne({ _id: id });
  },
  courseSubscriptions: function(){
    var id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
    return Subscriptions.find({course_id:id})
  },
  users: function(){
    return Meteor.users.find();
  }
});
```

and the template (which is garbage)  ps the course details come from a separate collection. It was easier and I think more performant to get the details separately and this works fine. It's just the username that I cannot display correctly:

```
<template name="adminCourseDetail">
<h1>Course Details</h1>
<p>Title: {{courseDetail.title}}</p>
<p>Description: {{courseDetail.description}}</p>
<p>Start Date: {{courseDetail.startDate}}</p>
<p>Number of sessions: {{courseDetail.sessions}}</p>
<p>Duration: {{courseDetail.duration}}</p>
<p>Price: {{courseDetail.price}}</p>
<p>{{userTest}}</p>
<a href="#">edit</a>
<a href="#">delete</a>
<h2>Course Subscriptions</h2>
{{#each courseSubscriptions}}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">{{username}}</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">{{sub_date}}</div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
</template>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, documents of the `Subscriptions` collection contain only the attribute `user_id`, referencing the corresponding user document in the `Meteor.users` collection. If this is the case, then you need to add an additional template helper which returns the username:

```
Template.adminCourseDetail.helpers({
  // ...
  getUsername: function() {
      if (this.user_id) {
        let user = Meteor.users.find({
          _id: this.user_id
        });
        return user && user.username;
      }
      return "Anonymous";
    }
  // ...
});
```

After that, just replace `{{username}}` with `{{getUsername}}`:

```
<template name="adminCourseDetail">
   <!-- ... -->
   <h2>Course Subscriptions</h2>
   {{#each courseSubscriptions}}
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3">{{getUsername}}</div>
         <div class="col-md-3">{{sub_date}}</div>
      </div>
   {{/each}}
   <!-- ... -->
</template>
```

Probably you misunderstood the concept of the **[`reywood:publish-composite`](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite)** package. Using `Meteor.publishComposite(...)` will just **publish** a reactive join, but it will not return a new set of joined data.

Comment: Thanks Matthias, I completely forgot that when calling a helper from within an each block, the helper is called in the context of the cursor you are looping through, therefore making data in that cursor accessible through use of 'this'. I got totally confused trying to figure out how to link the data from the collections. :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having a similar issue and looking at my specfic example. In my case the following code worked. Based on Matthias' answer:

In the template helper:

```
getUsername: function() {
  let user = Meteor.users.findOne({
      _id: this.user_id
    });
  return user;
}
```

and then in the template:

```
{{getUsername.username}}
```

My each block is looping through the cursor returned from the subscriptions collection rather than the course collection which is why it is simpler than the code Matthias provided.